# Sonar qualityprofile page does not display correctly using docker when data volume is mounted from disk.

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker, docker-compose, sonarqube5.1

I'm setting up a Sonarqube server and wanted to use the official dockerised version, but when I mount the data folders as volumes to preserve the state between restarts the QualityProfiles page fails to display the profiles.

The profiles are stored though, as I can see them in the 'compare profiles' dropdown, and they are preserved on restart.

I've tried on Safari and Chrome, and the behaviour is consistent.

There are no errors in the logs, and there are, as far as i can see, no permission issues, since the data is being written. Without mounting the data volumes it works fine, but the state is not persisted on restart, which is a deal-breaker..

Anyone else with this problem that has managed to solve it?

This is my docker-compose config

```
  sonarqube:
    image: sonarqube:5.1
    links:
     - db:postgres
    ports:
     - "9000:9000"
     - "9092:9092"
     - "5432:5432"
    environment:
     - SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/sonar
     - SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=sonar
     - SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=sonar
    volumes:
      - /data/sonar:/opt/sonarqube/data
    privileged: true
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
     - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sonar
     - POSTGRES_USER=sonar
    volumes:
     - /data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    privileged: true
```

And the docker versions 

`[ec2-user@xxxxxxxxx sonar]$ docker version
Client version: 1.6.2
Client API version: 1.18
Go version (client): go1.3.3
Git commit (client): 7c8fca2/1.6.2
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.6.2
Server API version: 1.18
Go version (server): go1.3.3
Git commit (server): 7c8fca2/1.6.2
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64`

Comment: It won't solve your problem, but I think `SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/postgres` should be `SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/sonar` and the port 5432 should be exposed in the definition of the `db` container instead of `sonarqube`.

Comment: Correct, that was a copy paste error. Fixing that...
The 5423 port will be accessible to the sonarqube image because its linked,but yes clients need to be able to access it as well so the sensible to export that from there. They have an interesting way of reposting 'issues' on the sonarqube project - only pull requests :) I'll do one to update their documentation..

Comment: I noticed the same behavior that in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30911874/sonarqube-rules-getting-disabled-on-startup). I'm continuing to investigate because I'm interested about that too ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `sonarqube` image doesn't use a volume for the `$SONARQUBE_HOME/extensions` folder. The first time that you use `docker-compose up`, sonar initialise the database and install 3 plugins: JAVA, GIT and SVN.

The second time you run `docker-compose up`, the database is already installed, but the `$SONARQUBE_HOME/extensions/plugins` folder is empty. So JAVA, GIT and SVN are no more installed and `sonarqube` disables the rules.

This `docker-compose.yml` file works as expected.

```
sonarqube:
  image: sonarqube:5.1.1
  links:
   - db
  ports:
   - "9000:9000"
  environment:
   - SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/sonar
  volumes:
   - /data/sonar/data:/opt/sonarqube/data
   - /data/sonar/extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions
db:
  image: postgres
  environment:
   - POSTGRES_USER=sonar
   - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sonar
  ports:
   - "5432:5432"
  volumes:
   - /data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

It still works after using `docker-compose rm` and you will be able to add other plugins.

A `VOLUME` instruction should be used in the Dockerfile that build the image. I will submit it to them.

Comment: Great spot!
It is a bit weird though that the rules show up in the drop down and they can be compared, even though they are disabled...